# how to handle touch events on list view when popup is being dismissed

Tags: android

I have a listView. Each list item is clickable. Each list item is a layout by itself.

On a button press I present a popupWindow on top of listView. I have set

```
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), ""));
    PopupWindow.OnDismissListener dismissListener = new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
               popWindowVisible = false;
               popwindow_dim_bg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    };
    popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(dismissListener);
```

Now my problem is when I touch outside of popupWindow onto listView, android executes the click listener of listView item

Whereas my desired behavior is to just dismiss popup if present else let the click go thru.

I tried `setOnTouchListener(return true)` on listView, but that did not help.

Can you help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, when you click outside the dialog, if there is any view, it will execute the onclick listener of the view.

In order to override that, use a boolean flag

You will have to do the following:

1. boolean isDialogOpen = false;
2. inside button click event, set isDialogOpen = true
3. inside onDismiss set isDialogOpen = false
4. in your listview item click, add an if block

   if(!isDialogOpen)
   {

   //your stuff here
   ....

   }

Comment: thanks I already did that. However, there are some problems with this approach....I will upvote but will not accept

Comment: so...the dismisslistener is executed before clicklistener. So the boolean flag will always be false when clickListener is executed. So I had to work around the problem by having a delay which is not clean solutio.

Comment: I just got hold of something. Can you pls try this and see if this works

`dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog.setOnCancelListener(
        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {


            }
        }
);`